# HMS and Huawei devices compatibility

Tags: android, firebase, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I would like to know the product models compatibles with HMS.

Such as Google : https://storage.googleapis.com/play_public/supported_devices.html

However, I cannot find the corresponding document for reference.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer,

Please refer :https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/emui-version-dependent-0000001050042515-V5?ha_source=hms1

HMS Core is pre-installed on all models of Huawei mobile phones. The features supported vary according to the EMUI version. For non-Huawei mobile phones, see the adaptation list. Only Android versions are differentiated.